# Boolean negation

Tags: boolean-logic

One of my exam questions reads:

```
! ( ! ( a != b)  &&  ( b > 7 ) )
```

The choices:

```
a) (a != b) || (b < 7)
b) (a != b) || (b <= 7)
c) (a == b) || (b <= 7)
d) (a != b) && (b <= 7)
e) (a == b) && (b > 7)
```

Initially, I thought it would be D. This is incorrect, and I realize why. I don't understand how the logical negation operator reverses && and greater than/less than. I believe I have narrowed it down to the first two. Is there any instance > would change to <= ?

Comment: Read up on [de Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Engineering).

Comment: i dont think any of these are correct

Comment: is B the correct answer?

Comment: Are you missing any parentheses?

Comment: double check if you typed the answers correctly

Comment: If the second ! applies only to '(a != b)' then B is correct.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - well, the question is tagged "Java"...

Comment: I've double checked, everything is entered correctly.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Last I checked, Java doesn't use some kind of custom boolean logic implementation. Which of course begs the question of *why* this question is tagged (and titled) Java.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: I must be missing something; which part of this would not be Java?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm sorry that I was not clear. I intended to say that this question is about vanilla boolean logic, as nothing in this question is specific to a Java interpretation or implementation of said logic. It's perfectly valid Java. And C#. And probably a half dozen other languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any instance > would change to <= ?

Answer: every time you negate it.

Consider `x > 1`. The negation of this is clearly `x <= 1`. If you simply negate it as `x < 1` then neither case covers the `x == 1` case.

---

That being said, the given boolean `! ( ! ( a != b)  &&  ( b > 7 ) )` can be decomposed as follows:

1. Given:

   `! ( !(a != b)  &&  (b > 7))`
2. Negate `a != b`:

   `! ((a == b)  &&  (b > 7))`
3. Distribute the `!`:

   `!(a == b) || !(b > 7)`
4. Negate `a==b`:

   `(a != b) || !(b > 7)`
5. Negate `b>7`:

   `(a != b) || (b <= 7)`

The answer is, therefore, B.

Comment: Your example with x > 1 explained it perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be B. This is because the negation next to the (a != b) is evaluated first, then you distribute the outside negation to the entire proposition.

Using DeMorgan's Laws, the && will switch to ||. Similarly, != becomes ==, and > becomes <=.

```
!(!(a != b) && (b > 7))
!((a == b) && (b > 7))
 (a != b) || (b <= 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
! ( ! ( a != b)  &&  ( b > 7 ) )

= ! ( (a = b) && (b > 7))

= (a != b) || (b <= 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

answer is B.
to understand this :
! ( ! ( a != b)  &&  ( b > 7 ) )

Lets break it into parts. 
Part dummy: (a!=b)
Part X: !dummy
Part Y: (b>7)

Now !X = double negate of dummy => dummy => (a!=b)

!Y = !(b>7) => b should not be greater than 7 => b should be less than or equal to 7 => (b<=7)

Now problem left is how && becomes ||

So original question is: !( X && Y ) => should not be (X and Y) => it should be either negate of X or it should be negate of Y, because if instead of X it is ~X, the condition (X and Y) becomes false and hence !(X and Y) becomes true and hence original condition is achieved. Similarly for Y.

Answer (score 0):

First apply the inner bracket logical NOT (`!`):

```
!(!(a != b) && (b > 7)) becomes !((a == b) && (b > 7))
```

With De Morgan's Law we reverse the operators to their counterpart.

We change `>` to `<=` because the `>` operator does not include 7 itself or anything less, hence the `<=` is the only one that satisfies that condition.

[image: Truth Table]

Now the outer `!`:

When looking at truth tables (picture above), you'll notice that logical AND (`&&`) and logical OR (`||`) have opposite results when comparing 2 different boolean expressions (i.e. truth false, false true), hence when we apply the `!`, we reverse the `&&` with `||`. Finally we need to switch the `==` to `!=` again.

All up, this produces:

```
((a != b) || (b <= 7))
```